# Why my Big Query account stopped collecting data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm using Firebase and BigQuery to monitor my mobile app activity.

Over the first few days, everything was smooth and I saw the `events_*` tables. However, days passed and suddenly Firebase stopped exporting data to BigQuery.

- I validated the BigQuery account - and it seems that this is not a payment-related kind of a problem.
- When I check the Firebase reports, everything looks OK and the data available.

Any idea what is causing the stop?

Comment: Which product from Firebase are you exporting to BigQuery?

Comment: Hi, I exporting ftom analytics

Comment: It's the same for me. What's the last exported table date?

Comment: I've seen some related questions to the app_events table not being exported to BigQuery. If you have confirmed that there are events in Firebase that should've been exported try contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) so they can look into this issue